# How to tell grep to match special character at beginning of each word

Tags: grep, regular-expression, quoting

I have certain questions regarding `grep`.

1. Why does the following command match '`<Hello`'?

   ```
   $ grep -E "\<H" test
   Hello World
   <Hello
   H<ello
   ```
2. What needs to be done to match '`<Hello`' only?

Comment: to match ' use `grep \' inputfile`

Comment: 1st Q. is wrong , I think

Comment: You should rephrase your question. Show the contents of your test file and simply tell us the number of the line you wish to match. There a lot of ambiguities in your question at the moment.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret Question edited.

Comment: @user3539 I guess you mean "`<Hello`" (no quotes) instead of "`'<Hello'`". Please clarify.

Comment: @l0b0 All words that starts with <. For example `<Hello` and `Hello <World`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent `grep` from interpreting a string specially (a regular expression), use `-F` (or `--fixed-string`):

```
$ cat test
one < two
Hello World
X<H
A <H A
I said: <Hello>
$ grep -F '<H' test
X<H
A <H A
I said: <Hello>
```

Remember to quote the search pattern properly, otherwise it may be interpreted badly by your shell. For example, if you ran `grep -F <H test` instead, the shell will try to open a file named "H" and use it to feed standard input of `grep`. `grep` will search for the string "test" in that stream. The following commands are roughly equivalent to each other, but not to the above:

```
 grep -F <H test
 grep -F test <H         # location of `<H` does not matter
 grep -F H test
 cat H | grep -F test    # useless cat award
```

As for matching words only, have a look at the manual page `grep(1)`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The
          test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning  of
          the  line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly,
          it must be either at the end of the line  or  followed  by  a  non-word
          constituent   character.    Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,
          digits, and the underscore.
```

Example usage (using the above test file):

```
$ grep -F -w '<H' test
A <H A
```

(`-F` is optional here as `<H` does not have a special meaning, but if you intent to extend this literal pattern, it may be useful then)

To match the beginning of a word, you do need regular expressions though:

```
$ grep -w '<H.*' test    # match words starting with `<H` followed by anything
A <H A
I said: <Hello>
```

Comment: The last one was I was looking for. I thought I could give `grep '\<<'` test to match `<` at beginning of each word. But it didnt work out. Any idea why it didnt work?

Comment: @user3539 possibly because `<` is not considered a word character. See the manual page under *The Backslash Character and Special Expression*

Answer (score 2):

`<` is not a special character in any grep. However, in GNU grep `\<` is special and means *the beginning of word* (so the zero-width boundary before `Hello` in all your input lines).

In all `grep`s `\` is special. It either can escape a special character to remove its special meaning (so it's matched literally) or add a special meaning to a character (that's typically used to introduce new operators without breaking existing scripts, another way is to use things that would otherwise be invalid like `*?` or `(?`) or for ANSI C escape sequences like `\n`, `\t`...

To remove the special meaning of `\`, like the others, you need another `\`.

So to match `<Hello`, you need:

```
grep -E '<Hello'
```

And to match `\<Hello`, you need:

```
grep -E '\\<Hello'
```

Note that both `<` and `\` are special *to the shell* as well so need quoting *for the shell* as well, hence the single quotes above (`\` is also special (to the shell) inside double quotes, though only in front of other special characters inside quotes like newline, double quote, backslash, dollar or backtick, so you'd nee `grep -E "\\\<Hello"` or `grep -E "\\\\<Hello"` to match `\<Hello`).

So that pattern matches the full line, add the `-x` option to grep:

```
grep -xE '<Hello'
```

would match only lines whose content it exactly `"<Hello"`.

To match at the beginning of the line:

```
grep -E '^<Hello'
```

(would match `"<Hello"` and `"<Hello world>"`, but not `World <Hello`.

To match `<Hello` not preceded by a non-blank character (my interpretation of your *at the beginning of a word*):

```
grep -E '(^|[[:blank:]])<Hello'
```

or with BRE:

```
grep '^\(.*[[:blank:]]\)\{0,1\}<Hello'
```

Comment: How to match < at beginning of word only?